# Who is the fastest runner with respect to his or her class?

Tags: statistics

An elementary school class ran one mile with a mean of 11 minutes and a standard deviation of three minutes. Rachel, a student in the class, ran one mile in eight minutes. A junior high school class ran one mile with a mean of nine minutes and a standard deviation of two minutes. Kenji, a student in the class, ran 1 mile in 8.5 minutes. A high school class ran one mile with a mean of seven minutes and a standard deviation of four minutes. Nedda, a student in the class, ran one mile in eight minutes. Who is the fastest runner with respect to his or her class?

Comment: in the future, show your progress towards the problem, as it'll help us target what exactly you are lacking in your solution

Comment: what have you tried

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: *"A high school class ran one mile with a mean of seven minutes and a standard deviation of four minutes."*  Some of those in the class must have run very fast (the men's world record is currently 3:43.13)

Answer (score 2):

Well, Rachel ran one standard deviation faster than the rest of her class, Kenji ran one-fourth of a standard deviation faster than his class, and Nedda ran one-fourth of a standard deviation slower than her class.

Can you evaluate who the fastest runner is from here?